# Difference between SET with SELECT vs SELECT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql, select, set

Is there a difference between the two queries? Are both correct?

```
SET price = (SELECT buyPrice FROM products WHERE productCode = product);

SELECT buyPrice INTO price FROM products WHERE productCode = product;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

With the `SET` syntax, you can only set one variable at a time, so the SELECT query must have only one expression in its select-list.

With the `SELECT INTO` syntax, you can set multiple variables. For example:

```
SELECT buyPrice, lastUpdated INTO price, latest FROM products ...
```